# Simple Eureka server authentication fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, java-17

I am developing a small microservices based application and I need to incorporate authentication in the Eureka server. Currently I have (Spring Cloud) Gateway, Eureka Server and a microservice, both Gateway and the microservice register correctly in Eureka. I use Spring Boot 3.1.2 and Java 17.
However, when I follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/reference/html/#authenticating-with-the-eureka-server)everything fails.

The error is:

```
2023-11-29T18:22:27.803+01:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m20880[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nfoReplicator-0][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m DiscoveryClient_TEST-SERVICE/test-service:e1c949b8-c432-4b9b-bca5-518ad97e8b3a - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:820) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

[2m2023-11-29T18:22:27.804+01:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m20880[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nfoReplicator-0][0;39m [36mc.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:820) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I show my configurations that does not work:
**application.yml** (Eureka)

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
server:
  port: 8761
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka
  security:
    basic:
      enabled: true
    user:
      name: prueba
      password: 123
```

**pom.xml** (Eureka)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Eureka</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.yml** (Microservice)

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: test-service
server:
  port: 0
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://prueba:123@${eureka.instance.hostname}:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}
```

Thank you in advance.
If you have any questions I remain at your disposal.